# opencv distance transform

Tags: opencv, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure if this is the right place for an OpenCV question, but I will ask nonetheless :) I want to compute distance transform on a cv::Mat object. However, for each pixel in the matrix, along with its distance to the nearest zero pixel, I want to identify the nearest zero pixel (row/col) as well. Is there any in-built OpenCV functionality to achieve this? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12380/opencv-distance-transform/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure but I think that is called the "nearest feature transform" and AFAIK it is not implemented in OpenCV.

In any case you only want to find the nearest zero feature of a **few of points** you can find it integrating the trajectory which start in your "working point" following the gradient of the distance transform image. On a few steps bounded by the sqrt(width*height) you will find eventually the nearest zero feature.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2011-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1